# Maui - Android.Views.View Create/Rendere from ContentPage

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui, .net-7.0

How can i render or create or convert a Maui object like a contentview or a grid into a platform specific view like a Android.Views.View in platform code in my case Android?

No idea actually how it works !

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Handler it will help you do this by using the PlatformView Property in your Native Partial class. Now what you can do is simply check this blog for which control uses what handler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/ and based on that you create your Handler.

Once it's ready you can use the PlatformView property in your Native Partial Class.

An example is below:

```
using System;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;
using AndroidX.Core.Content.Resources;
using AndroidX.Core.Graphics;
using AndroidX.Core.View;
using Maui.FreakyControls.Platforms.Android.NativeControls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Color = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color;

namespace Maui.FreakyControls
{
    public partial class FreakyEditorHandler
    {
        protected override AppCompatEditText CreatePlatformView()
        {
            var _nativeView = new AppCompatEditText(Context)
            {
                ImeOptions = ImeAction.Done,
                Gravity = GravityFlags.Top,
                TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.ViewStart,
            };
            _nativeView.SetSingleLine(false);
            var colorStateList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList(_nativeView, colorStateList);
            _nativeView.SetHorizontallyScrolling(false);
            return _nativeView;
        }

        internal void HandleAllowCopyPaste(FreakyEditor editor)
        {
            if (editor.AllowCopyPaste)
            {
                PlatformView.CustomInsertionActionModeCallback = null;
                PlatformView.CustomSelectionActionModeCallback = null;
            }
            else
            {
                PlatformView.CustomInsertionActionModeCallback = new CustomInsertionActionModeCallback();
                PlatformView.CustomSelectionActionModeCallback = new CustomSelectionActionModeCallback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check my library; it has a bunch of examples of native usage: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls